# Why would a webserver need to rely on "Host" header?

Tags: http, security, http-headers, webserver

I'm trying to understand vulnerabilities arising from HTTP(S) header `Host`. I heard that webservers may use the value of the `Host` header from incoming requests to do different stuff such as constructing URLs. For example here is a excerpt from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/security/#host-headers-virtual-hosting):

> Django uses the Host header provided by the client to construct URLs in certain cases.

I know that any information in HTTP(S) requests may not be trusted. Web servers know what host name they are behind. So why would they take it from `Host` header that cannot be trusted if they can have their host name configured manually?